# How to find and edit the file for fail2ban to change the email address it's using to send banned IPs to

Tags: email, fail2ban, ubuntu-16.04

Running Ubuntu 16.04 OS
Nginx server
Fail2Ban Ver 0.9.3

When I first did the install of fail2ban I believe it asked me for an email address.

I put in my personal email and I get spammed with all the IPs getting banned.  I don't mind it but I want to change the email address it has. But I'm unable to locate the correct file where I can change the email address it's sending to.

what is the filename I need to edit? What directory is this file in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to change the email address within the jail.conf

I use centos, but you should be able to search and find the same file.

/etc/fail2ban/jail.conf

#Sender email address used solely for some actions

sender = root@localhost

Comment: when i do service fail2ban status  I actually see my real email address not root@localhost

I'm looking to change the email address that fail2ban sends too

Comment: I'm sorry what about "service fail2ban status"?

Comment: output from the status command  where it has my_real_address@xxxx.com   this is where it's show my real email address

 to=MYREALEMAIL@X.COM, delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=30205, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (u75F8doN010195 Message accepted for delivery)
from=fail2ban, size=227, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201608051508.u75F8ewW010206@my.server.com>, relay=root@localhost
to=MYREALEMAIL@X.COM, delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=30240, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (u75F8fAK010271 Message accepted for delivery)

Comment: Yup, so like i said, you need to edit your jail.conf.  In that file you will find sender = my_real_address@xxxx.com.  Change it to whatever you like and restart the service.

Comment: I edited the jail.conf file to my_real_address@xxxx.com   and I did sudo service fail2ban restart and still getting emails to my personal email address  :(

Comment: Ok,  i had to login to the control panel of my domain and check and allow emails from fail2ban not to go to spam folder -  I'm getting the emails to the correct email address I want now but, for some reason I'm not getting any emails on on the ip address and the detailed info that I use to get

Comment: sounds like a different topic from the original question.  Might need to start a new thread and included the needed information to help.  i.e.  what you saw before, any changes you made and what you see now.